# Why aren't the newlines preserved in Symfony translation YAML files with the | (pipe)?

Tags: symfony, yaml, twig

According to [Symfony Documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml/yaml_format.html#strings), it is possible to use the `|` (pipe) symbol to

> indicate that the string will span several lines. In literals, newlines are preserved

I have a YAML file for my translations with a paragraph with new lines, let's say:

```yaml
test: |
    foo
    bar
    baz
```

In my twig template, I have:

```php
{{ 'test'|trans }}
```

The text displayed in my browser is:

> foo bar baz

Instead of:

> foo
> bar
> baz

Why aren't the newlines preserved?

Comment: Is this a translation problem or an html problem? Have you tried the [`nl2br` filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/nl2br.html)?

Comment: Please share more details - what have you tried to check whether linebreaks are preserved or not? Usually, a single line break within the markup is **not** rendered as a line break in your browser

Comment: @NicoHaase I should have clarified that by "displayed in my browser" I meant "what I see in the webpage" (and not in the console of my browser). And yes thanks, I actually got mixed up between string line breaks (\n) and HTML line breaks (<br>)!

Comment: @msg It's actually an HTML problem that I could have resolved alone with the solution Darius Mann gave and that I thought I tried. But I wouldn't have learned about the nl2br filter, which is exactly what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `nl2br` twig filter, line breaks in YAML don't automatically translate to `<br />` tag's in HTML.

`{{ 'test'|trans|nl2br }}`

Answer (score 1):

> indicate that the string will span several lines. In literals, newlines are preserved

I think this line makes reference to the .yml file itself. Keep in my that

```
foo
bar
baz
```

is rendered as HTML in you twig file. That means that if you don't put any (e. g.)`<br>` between the words it will render like

```
foo bar baz
```

Comment: Yes my mind got mixed up between newlines rendered in string (\n) and in HTML (<br>).
At some point I (think I) tried to add <br> with |raw filter in twig template but it displayed the tag escaped. I tried again just now and `<br>` tag in YAML file + `raw` filter after `trans̀ works!
Thanks.